# Query is not returning any rows with like '%' operator and left outer join, if right table has no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using **MS SQL SERVER 2008R2**. i have two tables A and B as

```
create table A(
id int primary key, name Varchar(20));

create table B(
id int primary key, user_name Varchar(20));

insert into A values(1,'A1');
insert into A values(2,'A2');
insert into A values(3,'A3');
insert into A values(4,'A4');
insert into A values(5,'A5');
```

Now my problem is :

```
select A.* 
from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id 
where B.user_name like '%';
```

**or**

```
select A.* 
from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id 
where B.user_name like '%%';
```

Above written query does not return any records even though left table have 5 entries in it. without any filter on right table it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
select A.* from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id
```

this query will give you out put like this...

```
id  name    id  user_name
1   A1  NULL    NULL
2   A2  NULL    NULL
3   A3  NULL    NULL
4   A4  NULL    NULL
5   A5  NULL    NULL
```

and you are comparing username using like with **null**

```
select A.* from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id where B.user_name like '%%';
```

hence it will not give you any output

you should try following query

**`select A.*,b.* from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id where (b.user_name like '%%' or b.user_name is null)`**

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario...first left join is happening it is finding 5 entries and then on that record set sql sever is applying filter of user_name and as user_name for all rows is null..no records are getting displayed.

you can change your query to

```
select A.* from A left outer join B on A.id = B.id where ISNULL(B.user_name,'') like '%%';
```

Comment: I got my answer, @Thanks a million to all of you to give that much of quick reply,

Answer (score 3):

You are using wild card for comparing null values as well,
Use this,

```
SELECT a.* FROM   a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE  b.user_name LIKE '%' OR b.user_name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all values in table B are `NULL`, any wildcard match on `NULL` values will return `NULL`.

So the condition `where B.user_name like '%';` translates into `where NULL like '%';` which evaluates to NULL as NULL cannot be compared with any value.

```
 select A.* from A left outer join B on 
 A.id = B.id where COALESCE(B.user_name,'') like '%%';

 select A.* from A left outer join B on 
 A.id = B.id where COALESCE(B.user_name,'') like '%';
```

supporting sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ca91/8

Note that the `COALESCE` is ANSI, and therefore supported in Oracle, SQL Server and PostGres and does shortcut evaluation. n

> **Edit:** Based on new information that this same query should work in all SQL Server, PostGres and Oracle. I am changing the SQL query to
>   use `COALESCE` instead which is supported in all
>
> Unless you use `ISNULL()` and check like this `where
>   ISNULL(B.user_name,'') like '%';`
>
> ```
> select A.* from A left outer join B on 
> A.id = B.id where ISNULL(B.user_name,'') like '%%';
>
> select A.* from A left outer join B on 
> A.id = B.id where ISNULL(B.user_name,'') like '%';
> ```
>
> See this fiddle 
>    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ca91/6

Comment: this is also correct but i can not use this because in my case the same query is running in Oracle,MS Sql Server & Postgresql database

Comment: @Krishna I've updated my answer based on this new information.Please consider marking this as answer, if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
select A.* from A
left outer join (SELECT * FROM B where user_name like '%') X on A.id = X.id;
```